# Почему возникает segmentation fault?

Tags: c++, c++11

Прохожу данное задание в курсе на Степике:
https://stepik.org/lesson/41560/step/4?discussion=821732&unit=20013

Условие:
[image]

Мой код:

```
    #include  <iostream>  
    #include <vector>  
    #include <algorithm>  

    using vector = std::vector<size_t>;  

int find(size_t i, vector& parent)
{
    while(i != parent[i])
        i = parent[i];
    return i;
}

void union_sets(size_t i, size_t j, vector& parent, vector& rank)
{
    int i_id = find(i, parent);
    int j_id = find(j, parent);
    if(i_id == j_id)
    return;
    if(rank[i_id] > rank[j_id])
        parent[j_id] = i_id;
    else
        parent[i_id] = j_id;

    if(rank[i_id] == rank[j_id])
        rank[j_id] += 1;
}

int main()
{
    size_t flag = 1;
    size_t n = 0;
    size_t e = 0;
    size_t d = 0;
    std::cin >> n;
    std::cin >> e;
    std::cin >> d;

    vector parent(n + 1);

    for(size_t i = 1; i < parent.size(); i++)
        parent[i] = i;

    vector rank(e + 1);

    for(size_t i = 1; i < rank.size(); i++)
        rank[i] = 1;

    for(size_t i = 0; i < e; i++)
    {
        size_t first = 0;
        size_t second = 0;
        std::cin >> first;
        std::cin >> second;
        union_sets(first, second, parent, rank);
    }

    for(size_t i = 0; i < d; i++)
    {
        size_t first = 0;
        size_t second = 0;
        std::cin >> first;
        std::cin >> second;
        size_t i_id = find(first, parent);
        size_t j_id = find(second, parent);
        if(i_id == j_id)
        flag = 0;
    }

    std::cout << flag << " ";

    return 0;
}
```

На 47 тесте происходит **ошибка**:
Failed test #47. Runtime error
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Все тесты из условия проходят. В чем может быть проблема? Спасибо.

Comment: Немного странноватый DSU, но причин падать как-то не вижу...

Comment: В дебагер его запустите и посмотрите что там происходит на 47 цикле

Comment: логика  в функциях отсутствует.  find(size_t i, vector parent) практически копирует вектор,  копирует его элемяент и возвращает копию parent[i].  В другой функции также какие то бесполезные сравнения  и присваивания.  Какой тест проходит ваш код, лично мне непонятно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Почему у вас размер массива `rank` вдруг установлен в `e + 1`? Он ведь должен иметь тот же размер, что и `parent`, т.е. `n + 1`. Очевидно, вы вылетаете за пределы `rank`, что и приводит к segmentation fault.

В остальном все выглядит нормально, хоть и местами нелогично. Удивляет неоправданная мешанина из `size_t` и `int`. Формально диапазона типа `int` может быть недостаточно для представления значений порядка 10<sup>5</sup>. Также непонятно почему `parent` передается в `find` *по значению*.